# Html rendering in ios

Tags: html, ios

In order to render html tags in the description section of my ios app . im using "core text extension"
Normally it is working 100%.
But sometimes its not working.It is displayng a blank section. 
ex - :

> COMITE DE SELECTION « ARTWIGO »
> COMMENT ÇA MARCHE ?
>  
> But et objectifs du comité de sélection
> Le but de notre comité de sélection est d’opérer un choix, réfléchi et cohérent, des artistes présentés par ARTWIGO ; ceci, afin de préserver la qualité et le niveau nécessaires au succès de l’application  et donc, de garantir la promotion des artistes.
> Cette sélection tient  compte de critères spécifiques à chaque type d’expression artistique.
> Le comité est composé de spécialistes, indépendants, reconnus dans chaque domaine proposé par « Artwigo » et venant d’univers différents ;
> Le comité de sélection est constitué  de 11 membres répartis de la manière suivante :
> - 3 membres « fondateurs » composant le bureau
> - 6 membres composant le comité consultatif.
> Christine Jamart, rédactrice en chef de l’Art Même. Bruxelles
> Carine Fol, Directrice Artistique de La Centrale Electrique. Bruxelles
> Joël Benzakin, Bela Edition. Bruxelles
> Jean-Louis Godefroid, Directeur Espace Contretype. Bruxelles
> André Goldberg, resonsable Secteur Arts Plastiques au Centre Culturel Jacques Franck. Bruxelles
> Emmanuel d’Autreppe, responsable de l’Annexe des Brasseurs (art contemporain). Liège
> La composition du  bureau du comité est la suivante :
> Le Directeur du Comité : Jean-François Picaud Laethier de Morfouace                             
> La  Secrétaire générale : Carole de Vleeschouwer     
> le  Rapporteur : Joël Van Audenhaege
> Le comité de sélection se prononce à la majorité des voix.
> Confidentialité   
> Le résultat des votes et leurs motivations ne sont pas fournis aux candidats.
> Les candidats sont juste informés, par email, de l’acceptation ou du rejet de leur candidature par la Secrétaire générale.
> Référence jfplm08-10-2012

Im rendering this using the folowing code structure

> htmlText = [htmlText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"''" withString:@"'"];
>       NSData *data = [htmlText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>       NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data options:nil documentAttributes:NULL];

```
[DTAttributedTextContentView setLayerClass:[CATiledLayer class]];
DTAttributedTextView  *_textView = [[DTAttributedTextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
_textView.textDelegate = self;
_textView.attributedString = string;
[self.view addSubview:_textView];
```

I dont know the reason but its not rendering properly
Is thr any solution for this issue
Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to use [FTCoreText](https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText) to get easily a good rendering

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, does this library have a function to increase height according to the content size

Comment: Yes you can easily do it, for this you have to edit coreTextStyle function, just don't forget to [disable arc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) for the FTCoreText files